# Populating Dropdown from PostgreSQL

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have been trying to get a drop down list for a html form populated from a column in a postgresql table. Since I'm very new to this I have not been able to get it working.  I have a bit of code that I have been trying to learn from and also get to work. I would like to have the values in the Circuit column to show in the drop down. The drop down box is showing up but when clicked to expand and show the values nothing shows up. Below is the table structure followed by the code that I have been fiddling with. Also I'm not receiving any errors from the Database connection. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Table Example:**

[image: Table Example]

**Code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
             <select name="circuit-id-dropdown">
               <?php
                $db = pg_connect("host=[Deleted] port=5432 dbname=PECO user=postgres password=[Deleted]")
                //or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
                $sql = pg_query(sprintf("SELECT Circuit FROM CIRCUIT_INFO"));
                var_dump($sql);
                die;
                while ($column = pg_fetch_assoc($sql)) {echo '<option value="'.htmlspecialchars($column['Circuit']).'"></option>';}
                pg_close($db);
               ?>
              </select>
           </div>
```

Comment: What are you getting if you run var_dump($sql); die; after your pg_query call?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. It's acting as if the PHP isn't even running.

Comment: Is your host containing the "http://" as in your example? In that  case it might be that the script is crashing and you have error printing turned off. Which is why you can't see the fatal error.

Comment: Try switching host to the actual ip address or the domain name without the protocol "http://", since it's not using http

Comment: Yes it did have the http:// I removed them and used an IP address. Still not working. I'm going to go take a look at my php.ini file and see if it has error printing turned off.

Comment: Also; a perhaps obvious point but have you ensured that php-pgsql package is installed on your server?

Comment: I got PHP to kick out error reporting. Looked like the code "or die('could not connect: ' . pg_lasterror()); was killing the script before it go to the var_dump($sql). The new error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\File location on line 138 Which is $sql query

Comment: In that case I would say it's worth a shot to just space separate the variables in the pg_connect string instead of using newline

Comment: I updated the code above the the most current. I'm still getting a syntax error on line 138 which is the sql query. The error is as follows. **"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\HurleyForms\newvisualreport.php on line 134"** which is this code '$sql = pg_query(sprintf("SELECT Circuit FROM CIRCUIT_INFO"));'

Comment: That is because you forgot the semi colon on the line above

Comment: I added in the semi colon and now the page will load and I'm not getting any errors. The drop down list is still empty

Answer (score 1):

Your pg_query() command doesn't look right.  Try this one:

```
$db = pg_connect("host=[Deleted] port=5432 dbname=PECO user=postgres password=[Deleted]") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$sql = pg_query($db, "SELECT Circuit FROM CIRCUIT_INFO"));
while ($column = pg_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $circuit = htmlspecialchars($column['Circuit']);
    printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>', $circuit);
}
pg_close($db);
```

The first parameter to pg_query needs to be the connection object ($db).  Also, the sprintf() isn't necessary since your SQL is just a simple string.  Even if you were including variable data in your SQL, doing it via sprintf() would not be the way to do it - prepared statements would be more appropriate.

Comment: I added the $db to the query and I'm still not getting any errors and my drop down list is still not populating.

Comment: I overlooked putting the description between the <option></option> tags. Does my revised answer work for you now?